# Find a sequence of $\alpha(t)$ such that $\sum_{t=1}^\infty\alpha(t)=\infty$ while $\sum_{t=1}^\infty{\alpha(t)}^2<\infty$

Tags: calculus

As described in the title, can we find a $\alpha(t)$ sequence that satisfies those two requirements?

Comment: Harmonic series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, a good choice is $a(t) = \frac{1}{t}$, since we know from comparison with integrals that: $\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^p} = \infty$ for $p \leq 1$ and  $\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^p} < \infty$ for $p > 1$